how to identify flicker and RTN noise in a frquency spectrum
how to develop a signal processing algorithm to identify flicker noise and RTN noise in a frequency spectrum.
Please help me.

Flicker noise has a power spectral density that goes down proportional to frequency offset (so is "1/f noise"), while RTN noise goes down as the square of frequency offset (and is a "White FM noise" source).
The existing signal processing algorithms that can be useful for identifying these noise sources are as follows:
Welch Power Spectral Density:  The existing Welch algorithm (and related Bartlett's method) is a popular approach for estimating power spectral density. As a short description, the time domain signal is divided into smaller duration overlapping blocks, and the resulting blocks are windowed and converted to the frequency domain using the  FFT. These FFT's are squared to provide a power spectral density (PSD) and the PSD's of each block are averaged for the final result. If this result in plotted log-log plot (dB scale versus log frequency) the slopes of that plot will indicate the regions dominated by those two noise sources, as well as other noise types (Flicker will have a -10 dB/decade slope, while RTN will be -20 dB/decade). The Welch algorithm is not difficult to implement but is already available with proper scaling and windowing in Matlab, Octave and Python's scipy.signal. The key parameters are the total duration of the capture (which results in improved averaging), and the number of samples per segment (which sets the resolution bandwidth of the measurement and therefore the lowest achievable offset frequency). I demonstrate the use (and misuse) of the Welch method at these other posts, and specifically how it results in a much lower noise estimate than a direct FFT of the entire sequence, and how it is appropriate for distributed noise signals not individual tones:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/79256/21048
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/87731/21048
Allan Deviation: RTS noise is non-stationary. For such non-stationary signals the two-sample variance is a useful tool to create consistent statistics of the signal (popularized for use on clocks and gyroscopes when computed and plotted versus various averaging times as the Allan Variance, AVAR and as the square root the Allan Deviation, ADEV). When similarly plotted on a log log plot vs Averaging Time $\tau$, the sources of noise become quite clear from their relevant slopes (see plot below). This tool is often used and interpreted with timing and position signals but can be applied to any noise source (so as an extreme example, instead of it being a measurement of "frequency instability" as used with timing/clock signals it can be a measurement of "financial instability" by replacing units of "Hz" with units of "dollars"). The algorithms to compute the Allan Deviation and related statistics are also available in Python through the popular 'allantools' library.
I provide more details on AVAR and ADEV at this DSP.SE link:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/53993/21048
One of my favorite charts providing a clear map of using power spectral densities, Allan Deviation and many other similar computations is Enrico's Chart of Phase Noise and Two-Sample Variances, by Enrico Rubiola (Thanks Enrico!).  Copied from that chart, the plot below shows the expected slopes for AVAR due to different noise contribution types, where "White-FM" which is what RTN would be would have an AVAR that goes down at $1/\tau$ on a log-log plot, and "flicker FM" has an AVAR that is constant independent of averaging time $\tau$ (so often referred to as the "Flicker Floor" for that reason).

For further details on both methods, I recommend the following:
Welch Method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method
Allan Variance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_variance
The welch method is available as a function welch in Matlab, Octave and Python's scipy.signal. Review the help that is available within those tools.
The Allan Deviation and Allan Variance is available as part of the allantools library in python. Install that library and review the help that is avialable with that tool.

How can I implement both Welsh PSD and Allan deviation to distinguish both flicker and RTN noises in the signal at a time ? Thanks .

For Welch it is what I described - use the Welch method to compute the PSD and plot it on a log log plot: flicker will have a -10dB/decade slope while RTN will have a -20 dB/decade slope.  I similarly describe what to look for in an Allan Deviation plot, just as I wrote

@bharsu did that answer your question? If one of the noise types is more dominant (in a given frequency or time range), then that is the slope you will see---it is often common to see a PSD (welch) where it drops -20dB/decade at lower frequencies (where RTN is dominant) transitioning to -10 dB/decade (where flicker is dominant) at higher frequencies, and then reaching the white noise floor at even higher frequencies- thus we see the contributions of each.

I'm interested in learning how Welch's method and Allan deviation can be used together to identify different types of noise in a signal. While Welch seems particularly adept at identifying flicker noise, and Allan deviation excels at finding random telegraph noise (RTN), I'm curious if there's a way to combine them for a more comprehensive analysis. Thanks.

Both methods are adapt at identifying both types of noise. I'm not sure you understood my response of how the noise would appear either in the Welch Spectrum and in the AVAR plot? Did the last comment I just made before this one make sense? See the last plot at the bottom of my post as an example as to what I am referring to.

Now I understood clearly. Thanks a lot. To prepare myself further, I'd be grateful if you could recommend some resources for in-depth study on both methods, please?
