PSD vs Squared Mag Spectrum for Estimating Signal Power
I was reading the docs for SciPy Spectral Analysis and starting thinking about a few things I couldn't figure out. They say that

The left plot can be used to read the height of the lobe, i.e., half sine’s squared magnitude of $1V^2$
. The right plot can be used to determine the noise floor of $10^{-3}V^2/Hz$
. Note that the lobe height of the averaged squared magnitude spectrum is not exactly one due to limited frequency resolution. Either zero-padding (e.g., passing nfft=4*len(x) to welch) or reducing the number of segments by increasing the segment length (setting parameter nperseg) could be utilized to increase the number of frequency bins.


As the docs suggested, I tried zero padding the Welch version:

I can totally understand why the PSD would be what you want to estimate a noise floor, since the noise here is inherently a power/Hz kind of thing. What I don't understand is:

Why does Welch's method decrease the lobe height so dramatically in the PSD, while it doesn't at all for the squared magnitude spectrum?

For the squared magnitude spectrum, why doesn't zero padding the Welch to the number of bins in the non-Welch periodogram decrease the noise floor down to a level more like the non-Welch periodogram? I thought the only reason it was higher in the Welch case was because there was less bins and thus more noise power per bin.

Is the reason that the lobe height is slightly over 1 for the squared mag spectrum periodogram because of the power addition between the signal and the noise at that frequency?

Here's why I'm interested: I have audio signals I want to analyze, and my priorities are accurate signal lobe heights and a smooth noise floor for easily detecting true spurs from noise fluctuations. As such, I intend to use Welch's method (with zero padding). However, I can't figure out if I should be using the PSD or the squared magnitude spectrum. On the one hand, it seems like the squared magnitude spectrum is better for lobe heights. On the other, lobe heights are meaningless (at least, they can only give an upper bound for the true power of the signal due to considerations like my question 2) unless we know the underlying noise floor at that frequency, which we can only get via the PSD. Obviously this isn't a unique problem; what's the standard way to get around this? For my purposes, I would love to be able to have a single plot from which I can get the signal power as the difference between the lobe height and the height of the surrounding noise floor (on a linear scale of course). Is that not possible even as an approximation, and the only way is to use PSD to estimate noise density, find then take the signal power at a frequency bin as the $\text{squared mag spectrum height} - \text{noise density} * \text{bin width}$?



How are you scaling each? Do you have code you can provide? The flat peak won’t be fixed by zero-padding, see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/93775/why-is-the-sample-spectrum-considered-inconsistent/93782#93782 If you want tight peaks and a flat noise spectrum, you probably need something like MVM. Also, the squared magnitude spectrum will give you the total power integrated over each narrow band, whereas the PSD gives you an estimate of the power at each center frequency, so it depends on what you’re looking for. If you have more questions I’ll try to write an answer tomorrow.

@Baddioes The plots are from the Scipy documentation I linked, code is there as well right above the part I quoted. Strange, it seems to me like they are clearly implying the flat peak would be fixed by zero-padding (in the part I quoted). I'll look into MVM! Clear answers to my three questions would still be much appreciated though.

@Baddioes Not sure why I didn't just try the zero padding myself initially; just did so and edited my question to reflect that.

Direct answers to questions asked are provided first, then necessary details are elaborated on further below:


Why does Welch's method decrease the lobe height so dramatically in the PSD, while it doesn't at all for the squared magnitude spectrum?


This is because each bin has a resolution bandwidth that typically is  wider than 1 Hz, and the power spectral density is power/Hz. Since the power in a tone has no bandwidth, the reported power will be less. For example if the resolution bandwidth was 100 Hz and the power in the tone was 20 dBm (100 mW), then the power spectral density as measured assuming no other noise sources within the resolution bandwidth for that bin would be 100 mW/100 Hz or 1 mW/Hz (0 dBm/Hz).  If we didn't scale for PSD and just wanted the power spectrum, the power of the tone would be given as 20 dBm.


For the squared magnitude spectrum, why doesn't zero padding the Welch to the number of bins in the non-Welch periodogram decrease the
noise floor down to a level more like the non-Welch periodogram? I
thought the only reason it was higher in the Welch case was because
there was less bins and thus more noise power per bin.


When properly scaled, zero padding has no effect on the reported power other than reducing scalloping loss. Zero padding does not change a resulting FFT but interpolates more samples between the FFT results otherwise given, providing more samples of the Discrete Time Fourier Transform (DTFT) which is a continuous function in the frequency domain. The DFT (and FFT which is an algorithm providing the DFT samples) is samples on the DTFT. (see further explanations below).


Is the reason that the lobe height is slightly over 1 for the squared mag spectrum periodogram because of the power addition between
the signal and the noise at that frequency?


Yes. The result for each bin is the total power within the resolution bandwidth of the measurement, so includes everything within the Kernel for the window used. (see more details below).


Here's why I'm interested: ...


We cannot have a single calculation since spurs (single frequency tones) and any related signals with bandwidth less than the resolution bandwidth of the measurement cannot be properly reported on a power spectral density. For the case of pure tones, they have no bandwidth and therefore a power spectral density measurement does not really have a meaning in that case. For those familiar with test equipment that measures phase noise, they may be familiar with this in that the resulting phase noise measurement (which is a two-sided power spectral density) does not properly show the magnitude for any spurs-- the phase noise measurement has been scaled by the resolution bandwidth of the measurement (typically many Hz and therefore reduced accordingly). For my spectral measurements and evaluations, I always create two plots: an FFT spectrum for power of tones and narrow band signals (narrower than the resolution bandwidth) and a power spectral density using Welch. I always provide the resolution bandwidth of the measurement as well to provide the complete picture.
Below shows an example I demonstrated for the 2024 DSP Online Conference where spectral techniques were used to determine the Equivalent Number of Bits (ENOB) for an A/D Converter, where we need to know the power of a test sine wave as well as the power density of the quantization noise.

Additional Details
The squared magnitude spectrum will accurately provide the total power per bin consistent with Parseval’s theorem with the following caveats:
The frequency domain FFT is scaled by the sum of the window applied prior to squaring the magnitude. (the window duration is the total number of samples $N$ prior to any zero padding applied).
Zero padding will significantly reduce errors due to “scaloping loss”. I recommend padding to 4 to 10 times the FFT length to reduce typical scalloping losses to less than 0.1 dB.  I show this in the plots given below where the ratio of zero padding is changed for various windows and the resulting scalloping loss (error from true power when a tone is not exactly on bin center). Message is zero pad when processing resources allow to virtually eliminate errors due to tones not being exactly on a bin center:

Each bin in the FFT result when scaled and squared will provide the total power within the resolution bandwidth of the measurement, which is inversely proportional to the total signal capture duration (in bins this is just $1/N$ resulting in a bandwidth in units of normalized frequency: cycles/sample) and then increased further by the window applied (if not a rectangular window). Typical windows increase the resolution bandwidth to 1.5 to 2.5 bins. Note, this duration $N$ is the total number of samples of the signal PRIOR to any zero padding, and the window duration itself is also $N$. This means zero padding has no effect on the resolution bandwidth and therefore does not effect the power result (when the FFT is scaled by the sum of the window prior to squaring).
The resolution bandwidth in units of bins is given as:
$$B = N \frac{\sum(w[n]^2)}{(\sum(w[n])^2}$$
Finally the result is increased by 3 dB or doubled in power when we wish to have the spectrum be "one-sided" which includes the positive and negative frequency components consistent with Euler's identity for a real sinusoid given as:
$$A\cos(\omega t) = \frac{A}{2}e^{j\omega t} +  \frac{A}{2}e^{-j\omega t}$$
Where the total power is the sum squared of the magnitudes of the exponential (two-sided) components as $(A/2)^2 + (A/2)^2 = A^2/2$.  Each two-sided component has the power of its magnitude squared $(A/2)^2 = A^2/4$ and thus the total power in the sinusoid is 3 dB higher as $A^2/2$.  For real signals we can choose to represent the spectrum as one-sided since the positive and negative frequency components are complex conjugate symmetric and thus have the same power. However for complex signals we must represent the spectrum as a two-sided spectrum since the positive and negative frequency components are independent.
When we select power spectral density instead of power spectrum in the common tools providing the Welch spectrum (in MATLAB, Octave and Python's scipy.signal), the tool will provide all the proper scaling above and then modify the level to report the result in units of power spectral density (power / Hz). This will typically reduce the reported power level in each bin (when the resolution bandwidth is > 1 Hz), however we could feasibly have a very long data capture and very low sampling rate such that the power reported is increased when scaled by the resolution bandwidth.
Below are other related posts I have provided regarding proper use and mis-use of the Welch periodogram:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/95687/21048
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/94704/21048
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/94517/21048
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/79256/21048

Alright, there's a lot to unpack here. What Scipy calls the "Energy Spectral Density" (what you call the magnitude squared spectrum) is not actually the scaling that is output by the Welch or Periodogram functions. The different scaling can be found at Periodogram (Welch) has different levels depending on length of segment/ resolution.

Why does Welch's method decrease the lobe height so dramatically in the PSD, while it doesn't at all for the squared magnitude spectrum?

For spectral estimators, bias and resolution are inherently linked. The less resolution you have, the more bias you will have. When you have less resolution, energy gets spread out more evenly across your whole spectrum, leading to bias in each frequency bin. Welch's is notorious for being a strictly biased spectral estimator, whereas the periodogram is asymptotically unbiased. This is demonstrated in my answer to Why is the sample spectrum considered inconsistent?. Welch's is biased low at the peaks, and biased high everywhere else. However, as pointed out in the first link, different scaling factors can affect how the bias plays out.

For the squared magnitude spectrum, why doesn't zero padding the Welch to the number of bins in the non-Welch periodogram decrease the noise floor down to a level more like the non-Welch periodogram? I thought the only reason it was higher in the Welch case was because there was less bins and thus more noise power per bin.

This goes back to our conversation on your other post Isn't this an example of zero padding increasing ability to resolve peaks?. Adding bins endlessly doesn't change the shape of the spectrum because there is no actual increase in resolution. While zero padding can, to an extent, help you locate the peak of a tone, it doesn't actually help you resolve anything better. Since bias and resolution are inherently linked, the reduced resolution of Welch's method leads to (sometimes significant) bias.
You should probably look into the topic of zero-padding and resolution more thoroughly. Zero-padding performs a sinc interpolation on the spectrum. A non-zero padded FFT and a zero padded FFT both sample the same underlying DTFT, just at different points. I believe the Crochier and Rabiner book (if I'm not mistaken) discusses this. Here's also another couple of links in which this idea is discussed further (link 1 link 2).

Is the reason that the lobe height is slightly over 1 for the squared mag spectrum periodogram because of the power addition between the signal and the noise at that frequency?

In this case, yes. This may change from trial to trial, though, as the periodogram is also an inconsistent estimator, so as the amount of data increases without bound, the periodogram will continue to bounce around the true value with some non-zero finite variance. So, don't be surprised if one trial it's below 1, one trial it's above, etc.

Here's why I'm interested: I have audio signals I want to analyze, and my priorities are accurate signal lobe heights and a smooth noise floor for easily detecting true spurs from noise fluctuations...

Comparing two different scalings probably isn't the way to go as it's not apples to apples. This is the reason I suggested MVM as an estimator. It is asymptotically unbiased, and has better properties with respect to consistency than the unmodified periodogram (it isn't exactly consistent, but the analysis is extremely involved in proving this). You will get much tighter peaks than Welch's, though not as tight as the periodogram, and a noise floor that has much less variance than the periodogram, though the noise floor of Welch's will have less variance. It's kind of a tradeoff of the two. If you want to compute MVM and give it a try, see Computing modern spectral estimation techniques with FFTs.


I think you're slightly mistaken: the "Squared magnitude spectrum" (SMS) plotted in my attachment -- taken directly from SciPy docs, title and all -- IS the direct output of SciPy's Welch with scale='spectrum'. This is (I've verified this) the squared magnitudes from the FFT, averaged over windows, multiplied by 2/(square of summed window coefficients). In other words, it's what your linked SE answer calls the "Power Spectrum", NOT what that answer calls the "SMS". (For the record, I think the linked SE answer's terms make way more sense!)

I don't see how SciPy's "Energy Spectral Density" (ESD) fits into this. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like you're saying that that's what the SE answer calls the SMS (averaged FFT squared magnitudes with no scaling). But SciPy says ESD has units of $V^2 s / \text{Hz}$, while SciPy's SMS (SE answer's "Power Spectrum") has units of $V^2$ and I don't see how you could lose those units by multiplying by a dimensionless scaling factor 2/(square of summed window coefficients)
